# How do I use a class that has been added by the append in jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<input class="typeahead" id="jj" type="text">
<a href='#' id="a">add input</a>
```

i do append to add more inputs to html with class in the same class input in html
JS:1:

```
$("#a").each(function() {
$(this).on("click", function(){
     $('#jj).append('<input class="typeahead" type="text"');
});});
```

this is do autocomplete for class 
JS:2:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
          return function findMatches(q, cb) {
          var matches, substringRegex;
          matches = [];
          substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
          $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
          if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
          matches.push(str);
          }
          });

          cb(matches);
          };
          };
         var mmm;
         $.post('arrays.php',{},function(data){
         mmm = data;
         },"json")
         .done(function() {
            $('.typeahead').each(function(){
            $(this).typeahead({
                  hint: true,
                  highlight: true,
                  minLength: 1
                  },
                  {
                  name: 'medicinses',
                  source: substringMatcher(mmm)
           });
     });
});
```

how do i use class "typeahead"?

Comment: Where you want to use `ggg` class?

Comment: Do you want to attach anything to this element??

Comment: $('.ggg').each(function(){
       //someting
});

someting like that??

Comment: what code will be there in each loop??

Comment: @OmerCohen Please add this in question and also add what you want to do with `.ggg`

Comment: Milind Anantwar - yes

Comment: Milind Anantwar - autocomplete it work for me only for first input
i want to any inputs

Comment: @OmerCohen Share the code of `autocomplete` also in the `QUESTION`

Comment: It's better to `close` this question as it is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete do not support event delegation. You will need to attach the autocomplete to newly added element.

append will add the element at last position. You can target it using `:last` selector from collection of elements `.ggg` in `#kkkk`

```
$('button').click(function(){
 $('#kkkk').append("<input type='text' class='ggg'/>");
 $('#kkkk .ggg:last').autocomplete({
   //BIND SOURCE HERE
 });
});
```

Comment: :last is give to the last input.
i want to all inputs is add will has autocomplete

Comment: as i already stated, you can not do that. However this will bind autocomplete to all required inputs. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var mmm;
$.post('diagnoses.php',{},function(data){
              mmm = data;
    },"json")
    .done(function() {
                $('.ui-widget .auto').autocomplete({
                    source: mmm
                });
        });
$('#a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
    $('<input class="auto" type="text" placeholder="שם אבחנה">').appendTo('.ui-widget');
            $('.ui-widget .auto').autocomplete({
                 source: mmm
            });
    });
});
```